# Public static resource not visible

Tags: static-resources, public

I created a static resource and set the Cache Control to Public.  However, when I access the static resource URL directly, I get the Salesforce login page.  Here's the URL I'm using:

```
https://someorg--c.na168.visual.force.com/resource/1646404269000/building_on_crescent
```

The resource is an image file.  It is not contained within a Zip file.

Are there other settings I need to update in order for the static resource to be accessible?

Comment: Please don't add the "answer" as an edit of the "question". There's an answer spot down below. You are free to self-answer your own questions if you discover a solution.

Comment: @sfdcfox I thought I needed to wait 48 hours to do that.  The waiting period is no longer a requirement for StackExchange?

Comment: You can answer immediately, but you cannot "accept" your own answer for 48 hours. It's always been this way, as far as I recall.

Answer (score 4):

When I enabled this Session Setting, the problem was resolved:

Enable Content Sniffing protection

Comment: I have tried this and it is not working.