# Static Resource with Cache Control set to Public is not Loading on external website for external users

Tags: lightning-web-components, static-resources, chat, embedded-services

We are deploying Salesforce chat with Embedded Service deployments. Currently when users without access to SFDC view the chat, all of the Salesforce images show up as broken.

[image]

Below is an example of a Static Resource that I have uploaded. I figured that setting the Cache-Control to "Public" would give external users access to the static resources, but unforuntately that is not the case.

[image]

Another [stackoverflow thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/370795/public-static-resource-not-visible) here said to Enable Content Sniffing protection. Which I have done... Yet this still does not resolve the issue.

When I navigate to the URL of the Logo, Salesforce actually asks me to login. So this tells me that the user just cannot access the resource because they do not have a SFDC login.

My questions are:

1. What is the use of setting the cache to Public?
2. How can we serve images and other resources out to external users while having salesforce host the files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the use of setting the cache to Public?

It allows the cached data to persist beyond the current session.

> How can we serve images and other resources out to external users while having salesforce host the files

You need to use a Digital Experience or Site to serve the file. In other words, you can't use:

```
https://naXX.salesforce.com/resource/resourceName
```

but instead use the DE or Site's URL:

```
https://mySiteDomain.com/s/resource/resourceName
```

Also, make sure that the DE or Site does not require a login.

Comment: I created the DE and confirmed that Guest users can see and interact with the site without logging in. https://xxx--partialcpy.sandbox.my.site.com/support/s/resource/1682082611000/Earth is still showing a broken image. If I use the DE, is there another place I should be uploading the static resource?

Comment: The url that you suggested brings me to "Invalid Page"

Comment: @MatthewMetros I don't have time for this right now, but try this: create a Visualforce page with the code `{!URLFOR($Resource.myResource)}`, put that page on the site, and see what the URL looks like when viewed through the site.

Comment: Yup, that did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: there should be no '../s/..', from example above https://mySiteDomain.com/resource/resourceName