# Images are not displayed on mobile devices in Chrome/Safari, but displayed on Desktop for same users

Tags: experience-cloud, customer-community-plus

I have an Experience Cloud site which will be used mostly by mobile users through regular browsers. I've built the component, that displays images+text, the code snippet is like this:
Html:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <article class="slds-card no-border-style">
            <div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner">
                <div if:true={imageUrl}>
Image component      -->   <img src={imageUrl} alt={heading} class="full-width margin-t-1" />
                </div>
...
```

The url set's up like this:

```
<targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
            <property name="imageUrl" type="String" />
...
```

And has this format:
https://%DOMAIN_NAME%.vf.force.com/resource/1702294830000/Name

The issue is that for the same Community Plus user, the images display fine, but on mobile devices, they are just question marks in the boxes.

The link to the resources is in the **Trusted URL**s

There is no usage of FORM_FACTOR for this component or any specific logic for mobile devices.

**UPD** It seems that in incognito mode I have problems with displaying on the desktop as well, so it seems like that link is available for platform-logged-in users only. If any one what setting should be enabled for Community plus profile, please, tell

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with a link to static resources. The correct link should be starting with the experience cloud site's domain name.

More details here: [Static Resource with Cache Control set to Public is not Loading on external website for external users](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/401956/static-resource-with-cache-control-set-to-public-is-not-loading-on-external-webs)